# File writing permission denied in mod_wsgi deployed app

Tags: mod-wsgi, pyramid

I'm trying to deploy a Pyramid app using mod_wsgi on Apache.

I get `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` on templates folder, where mako caches his templates, **even if I grant write permissions to anybody**.

If I remove template caching from my ini file the site runs flawlessly.

I also tried running Apache as the user owning the folder instead of `www-data` with no luck.

Any clue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an Apache permission issue,

I had to change owner of folder to `www-data` user and set permissions to `775`

```
chown -R www-data:www-data ~/data
chmod -R 775 ~/data
```

Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960241/svn-permission-denied/960263#960263) but note for Mako `664` permissions will not be enough