# Allow aa-exec temp user to gain access to a folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, apparmor

I am currently working on a bash script which has a user that is created for the job it is running. The user does not exist outside of the script. I am trying to test my code coverage while leaving the user intact.

```
exec aa-exec -p test-user -- coverage run --source=/test/server ./main.py
```

The problem is that the test-user does not have access to the code coverage folder. After running `chmod -R 777 /usr/local/bin/coverage` I still get `/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/usr/local/bin/coverage': [Errno 13] Permission denied`. I have also tried to temporarily elevate the user inside the bash script using sudo, but because the user only exists inside the file, the sudoers file throws an exception.

I am currently out of ideas since the permissions for this user have to remain restricted ideally. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked, that the user has access to each of the directories above?

I.e. the user needs to have 'x' and 'r' rights to each of these directories:

```
/usr
/usr/local
/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: The permissions for all 3 folders have a consistent pattern  allowing read and execution for all groups and users I think. Most follow these permissions drwxr-xr-x

Comment: the **last three** characters of all directories aboce must have 'x' and 'r' in them. Do they?

Comment: could be also selinux. See f.ex.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960241/cant-open-file-svn-repo-db-txn-current-lock-permission-denied